# Two swapped edges

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I have 4 solved sides and 2 swapped edges. For a visual example: yellow white, green and blue are solved, and the f2l for red and orange is done, as are the corners, but for red there is an orange edge and vice versa. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap the edges in a solved Rubik's cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10753/swap-the-edges-in-a-solved-rubiks-cube)