# How to fix swapped edges in a 5x5 rubik's cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I have a 5x5 Rubik's Cube in a similar situation to this previous post - entirely solved, except for a pair of swapped edges: [Swap the edges in a solved Rubik's cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10753/swap-the-edges-in-a-solved-rubiks-cube#).

However, since it's a 5x5, it's the full edge (3 pieces) that's swapped:

[image: 3-piece edge is swapped from orange to red and vice versa]

It must be some kind of mistake, and I suspect that one of my kids swapped some center pieces. All six centers have removable faces, but no other pieces do. What I should do?

Answer (score 1):

This should not be possible. If we consider only the "odd-numbered columns" in every 5x5 grid then we have a 3x3x3 Rubik's Cube with two edge pieces swapped and it is well known this is impossible. Therefore we cannot solve the 5x5x5 cube.

Comment: This is correct, but as the OP says that the centre caps are removable, it can be made solvable fairly easily. Just shift a middle layer one quarter turn, and rearrange that layer's centre caps to match the corners (i.e. arrange them as if to undo that quarter turn).

Comment: Thanks Jaap - I tried your suggestion on shifting the 6 center pieces one quarter turn, and I don't think it solved the issue. It's totally possible that I didn't fully understand you. But after shifting the 6 center pieces, I tried to re-solve the cube. (I wasn't sure what you meant by matching the corners.) Upon trying to re-solve, the edges still weren't fixed. To be more explicit, for the top row, instead of orange-red-red-red-orange (and vice-versa on the other side), I now had orange-red-orange-red-orange (and vice-versa on the other side). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @RMagill: That final configuration you reached **is** solvable, because it is simply a pair of 2-cycles, so [two commutators suffice](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096592/21820).